# How to find the mean values based on the quarters of a year

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean

I would like to find the mean values based on the quarters of a year. To elaborate, I have a dataframe with two columns, named "year" and "earning". The "year" column contains quarter values such as (1998-Q1... 1998-Q4). I want to find the mean value of the quarters. Currently, I have a working solution but it will not be practical if there are more years. Is there a better solution?

```
data = {
    'year': ['1998-Q1', '1998-Q2', '1998-Q3', '1998-Q4', '1999-Q1', '1999- 
    Q2', '1999-Q3', '1999-Q4'],
'earning': [2800, 2544, 2511, 3104, 2793, 2570,  2600, 3287]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

# What if there are more years? For example 2000, 2001, 2002 .... 2018.
df_1998 = df.iloc[:4].mean()
df_1999 = df.iloc[4:].mean()

print(df_1998)
print(df_1999)
```

Comment: you can use `df.groupby(df.year.str[:4])['earning'].mean()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach was to convert the `year` column to a [PeriodIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.PeriodIndex.html) and then use [pd.Grouper](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) to return each year's mean.

```
df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year']).dt.to_period('Q')
df.set_index('year', drop=True, inplace=True)
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='A')).mean()  # freq='A' specifies yearly frequency where year-end is calendar year-end
```

Which outputs the mean earnings of each year, all inside one dataframe:

```
        earning
year    
1998    2739.75
1999    2812.50
```